# How can I share identical image files between different entries in an iOS Asset Catalog Image Set?

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog

I have an image set in my asset catalog, which has the following sizes:

- On the iPhone, 320x320 (@1x), 640x640 (@2x), and 960x960 (@3x)
- On the iPad, 640x640 (@1x) and 1280x1280 (@2x)

So I've created 4 files: `MyImage-320.png`, `MyImage-640.png`, `MyImage-960.png` and `MyImage-1280.png`.  I add them to the image set, and now I have five images: `MyImage-320.png`, `MyImage-640.png`, **`MyImage-641.png`**, `MyImage-960.png` and `MyImage-1280.png`.

`MyImage-640.png` and `MyImage-641.png` are identical.  Is there a way for me to tell Xcode to use the same image file for both?  If I don't, will my app be bigger, or is there some optimisation further down the line that catches it?

Comment: Use .pdf vector graphics when possible, it saves you a lot of hassle with the sizes. Then you have one file that you can use for all sizes. Don't forget to activate "Preserve Vector Data"

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have that option.  Also, wouldn't that give me the wrong size on the iPad?  The iPad 1x asset is the same as the iPhone 2x asset.